# Grub Shell: Boot without graphics drivers

Tags: grub2, graphics, rescue

At boot, instead of the usual Menu, I am greeted with the Grub Shell. I know how to set the linux kernel and inintrd image, but using the `boot` command also apparently loads the GPU drivers (my graphics card doesn't work), while previously I had set `nomodeset` in the config. My question is, how can I boot into the OS without loading the Graphics Drivers.

My OS is Debian Buster Based Deepin 20, if that helps.

Comment: you could try booting into single user mode ... add `1` to kernel command line ... then edit your config to exclude the drivers

Comment: could you please provide more detail on how to boot into single user mode from the grub rescue shell